# $\mathbb{N}$ in intensional MLTT with judgmentally commutative $+$ and $\times$

Tags: type-theory, dependent-type, typed-lambda-calculus

Is there a way to implement natural numbers in intensional Martin-Löf type theory so that addition and multiplication is judgmentally commutative?

Comment: I'm glad you are asking all those questions. I recall that, a couple of years ago, when I tried to get into dependent type theories, I found it hard to find what had been tried, what had been proven. Like many active areas of research, that field lacks an up-to-date summary of the state of the art.

Comment: Yes, just throw in those judgemental equalities. It's consistent.

Comment: @AndrejBauer what if I don't want to change the equality checking algorithm?

Comment: But you *must* change it (if you want it to be complete) because you are introducing *new* judgemental equalities.

Comment: No I meant that I want a type $T$ with two judgmentally commutative binary operations on it such that externally we can prove there is a bijection from the set of closed terms of $T$ to the usual natural numbers respecting the operations. I don't want to introduce any new rules to type theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible.

1. Suppose that we have such a type $T$, with an implementation of addition $\mathit{add} : T \to T \to T$, which is judgementally commutative.
2. Because MLTT is strongly normalising, we know that we can put $\mathit{add}$ in $\beta$-normal, $\eta$-long form.
3. Now suppose that we have two variables $x, y$ of type $T$.
4. Now consider the terms $\mathit{add}\,x\,y$ and $\mathit{add}\,y\,x$.
5. Substituting $x$ and $y$ for the formal parameters of $\mathit{add}$ will not create any new $\beta$-reducible expressions, because $x$ and $y$ are neutral terms.
6. Now, $\eta$-expand the occurences of $x$ and $y$ as demanded by the definition of $T$.
7. Now, the resulting terms will be identical except that we've permuted the occurences of $x$ and $y$.
8. Recall that judgemental equality for $\beta$-normal, $\eta$-long terms is just $\alpha$-equivalence.
9. Since we assumed $\mathit{add}\,x\,y$ and $\mathit{add}\,y\,x$ were assumed to be judgementally equal, this means that the normal forms for these two terms are $\alpha$-equivalent.
10. Since anywhere that $x$ occurs in the normal form for $\mathit{add}\,x\,y$, a $y$ occurs in the corresponding position of the normal form for $\mathit{add}\,y\,x$, the only way that these two terms can be $\alpha$-equivalent is if neither $x$ nor $y$ occurs in the term.
11. This means that $\mathit{add}\,x\,y$ and $\mathit{add}\,y\,x$ do not use their arguments!
12. As a result, we can conclude that $\mathit{add}\,1\,1$ and $\mathit{add}\,0\,0$ are also judgementally equal.
13. Therefore $T$ cannot be the natural numbers, since $2$ and $0$ must *not* be judgementally equal.

Comment: Could you explain step 9 in more detail?

Comment: @einzwein How's that?

Comment: It seems that I've given pretty much the [same answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/47942/why-is-plus-comm-a-b-equiv-refl-plus-a-b-not-a-proof-of-the-commutativity/47944#47944) for another question.

Answer (score 1):

[CoqMT (Coq Modulo Theory)](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01664457/file/final-version.pdf) was an extension of the Coq proof assistant that allows one to parametrize a development with a decidable first-order theory T. Since equality on natural number expressions with addition and multiplication is decidable, this would be a valid application of CoqMT. Unfortunately, the [implementation](https://github.com/strub/coqmt) has not been updated in over 10 years.